# Run Scrapy on IIS

Tags: iis, scrapy, scrapyd

I have an IIS server and on it I have an ASP.NET MVC application. The MVC application will revolve around Scraped data. Is there a way I can run [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) (a tool built in Python) on IIS? Simliar to how we can run PHP and WordPress on IIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Scrapy Tool](https://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/commands.html) does not need a web server to run, and yes you can [install it on Windows](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html#windows).  If you are talking about using a graphical web-based interface you may have to write your own or you can keep up with the latest efforts on [the mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/scrapy-users/gui).

Comment: So I can just do a cron job to run scrapy on the computer machine running Windows server? And it'll work just fine, like it does on a regular computer?

Comment: Well, if you can run Scrapy on the server in a shell with a terminal then sure, you can run it from a cron job.